# ggplot2 issue with facets and turning off clipping

Tags: r, ggplot2

It used to be possible to put text on plot margins by turning off clipping. In ggplot2_2.2.0 this doesn't seem to be possible anymore in plots that use facets (but still works if no facets are used). I've posted an issue [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1929) but it has not been addressed yet. Any ideas for workarounds in the meantime would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a minimal (non-)working example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

df.plot = data.frame(x = 1, y = 1, facet = 'facet', stringsAsFactors = F)
df.text = data.frame(x = 1, y = -0.3, label = 'test', facet = 'facet', stringsAsFactors = F)

p = ggplot(df.plot,aes(x = x, y = y))+
  facet_grid(~facet)+ # 'test' is only printed outside of the plot if faceting is turned off
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(data = df.text,aes(x=x,y=y,label=label))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 2),ylim=c(0,2),expand=F)+
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(2,2,2,2),"cm"))
gt = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] = "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```

Comment: `gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel-1-1"] = "off"`

Comment: great, this removes the clipping for the first panel. to remove all clippings, the following works: `gt$layout$clip = "off"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that with merging [this pull request](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/2539), it is possible now to have configurable clipping with `ggplot2`.

I think you just need to add `clip = "off"` in the `coord_cartesian` function. So that should solve the need of doing `gt = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))` fallowed by `gt$layout$clip = "off"`.

That is, this should suffice (tested with `ggplot2` version 3.1.0):

```
p = ggplot(df.plot,aes(x = x, y = y))+
  facet_grid(~facet)+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(data = df.text,aes(x=x,y=y,label=label))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 2),ylim=c(0,2),expand=F, clip = "off")+ # added clip = "off"
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(2,2,2,2),"cm"))
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, as I mentioned in [Annotate outside plot area once in ggplot with facets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54189807/5193830), you can make use of `cowplot::draw_label`:

```r
cowplot::ggdraw(p) + cowplot::draw_label("test", x = 0.53, y = 0.13)
```

[image]