# Annotate outside plot area once in ggplot with facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add an annotation outside the plotting area in a faceted ggplot. I can get the annotation that I want, but it's repeated for each facet. How can I get this annotation to appear only once?

E.g., to annotate "XX" once in the top left hand corner I can use:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(.~cyl ) + 
  annotate("text", x = -20, y = 36, label = "XX") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(50, 350), ylim = c(10, 35), clip = "off")
```

[image: annotated plot]

However this actually annotates it to the top left of each facet.

How can I get this to only appear once?

Comment: Only ggplot2. May be version issue - I have v3.0.0

Comment: OK. my mistake then .

Comment: It's an argument to the latest v 3.1 also: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_cartesian.html

Comment: Maybe try [cowplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html) for annotation.

Comment: [geom_text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53027319/786542) works too

Comment: @Tung I've tried some geom_text options, including your link, but I can't get anything to work or even plot off  the plot area

Comment: @Umaomamaomao: works for me with the latest `ggplot 2 v3.1.0`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can put a single tag label on a graph using `tag` in `labs()`.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
     geom_point() +
     facet_grid(.~cyl ) + 
     labs(tag = "XX") +
     coord_cartesian(xlim = c(50, 350), ylim = c(10, 35), clip = "off")
```

[image]

This defaults to "top left", though, which may not be what you want.  You can move it around with the theme element `plot.tag.position`, either as coordinates (between 0 and 1 to be in plot space) or as a string like `"topright"`.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
     geom_point() +
     facet_grid(.~cyl ) + 
     labs(tag = "XX") +
     coord_cartesian(xlim = c(50, 350), ylim = c(10, 35), clip = "off") +
     theme(plot.tag.position = c(.01, .95))
```

[image]

Comment: Note that while all answers here produce the desired result, this one seems the most direct, which is why I've accepted

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer -- however, I get this error: `"plot.tag.position" is not a valid theme element name.`

Comment: @jjrr I believe this was [introduced in ggplot2_3.0.0](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features-1).  I am currently using ggplot2_3.1.0 and `plot.tag.position` is working fine for me in `theme()`.

Comment: yeah, sorry -- I just realised indeed I was on a older v

Comment: I run the codes and get this error: Error in coord_cartesian(xlim = c(50, 350), ylim = c(10, 35), clip = "off") : unused argument (clip = "off").  I  don't know why. @aosmith

Comment: I can't reproduce the error message in **ggplot2** version 3.1.1, @Revo. What version of **ggplot2** are you using?

Answer (score 3):

It's in fact very easy, just have a *vector* of labels, where the ones you don't want to plot are the empty string `""`.

```
library("ggplot2")

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate("text", x = -20, y = 36, label = c("XX", "", "")) +
  facet_grid(.~cyl ) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(50, 350), ylim = c(10, 35), clip = "off")
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh yes, the old bait-and-switch

Comment: @Umaomamaomao I tried the same with `geom_text` and it doesn't work, afaik, it must be `annotate`.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, the package [`cowplot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/index.html) has the handy annotation function `draw_label()`. When used in combination with `ggdraw()`, can annotate anywhere on the canvas/sheet with the coordinates ranging from 0 to 1 (relative to the entire canvas). The function `cowplot::draw_label()` uses `ggplot2::annotation_custom()` under the hood.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
#> Warning: package 'cowplot' was built under R version 3.5.2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'cowplot'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     ggsave

# Revert to default theme; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41096936/5193830
theme_set(theme_grey())

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ cyl)

ggdraw(p) + draw_label("XX", x = 0.02, y = 0.97)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

With `geom_text`:

```
dummy <- data.frame(cyl = c(4), l = c("XX"), stringsAsFactors = F)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data=dummy, aes(label=l), x = -20, y = 36) +
  facet_grid(.~cyl ) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(50, 350), ylim = c(10, 35), clip = "off")
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and thanks for contributing :-) So then `geom_text` works ? Please consider adding a picture showing the results like in the other answers.

Comment: @GabrielDevillers I don't think new users can add images, which is a bit silly - I always forget what "privileges" who has